# Predefine function's parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.x

I need to predefine functions' parameters once, then use that functions somewhere else without passing arguments to them.

Like so:

```
@predef  
def foo(x):
    print(x)

foos = foo("hello"), foo("world")

for f in foos:
    f()

>> hello
>> world
```

Everything working as I wanted. But decorator looks tricky.

```
def predef(f):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                yield f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper(*args, **kwargs).__next__
    return decorator
```

I feel that there is simpler way to do that. Is it?

Comment: [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: You need to convert a non-nullary function into thunk, correct?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, going to read about it,  thx.

Comment: @bipll, din't hear about it before, but I think yes.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific example:

```
>>> foos = lambda: print('hello'), lambda:print('world')
>>> for f in foos: f()

hello
world
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember this. But it will be tricky for more complex things.